# React Bootstrap map not rendering

Tags: reactjs

The following code does not render in the dom and I cannot figure it out. From Debugging it seems to have the correct values as it iterates over the map.

```
//import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Dropdown from "react-bootstrap/Dropdown";
import "react-dropdown/style.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const tasks = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "First Menu",
    content: "This is content 1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Second Menu",
    content: "This is content 2",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Third Menu",
    content: "This is content 3",
  },
];
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <TTDDropdown />
    </>
  );
}
function TTDDropdown() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dropdown>
        {tasks.map((mytasks) => (
          <Dropdown.Menu key={mytasks.id}>
            <Dropdown.Item eventKey={"content-" + mytasks.id}>
              {mytasks.title}
            </Dropdown.Item>
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        ))}
      </Dropdown>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If I replace all bootstrap elements with an `div`, it works as expected. Might just be a CSS issue where you dropdown isn't visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are forgetting to add `<Dropdown.Toggle>` on top of the `Dropdown.Menu`
2. `<Dropdown.Menu>` should not be part of the loop. Only the `Item`s should be looped

Heres the code that makes it work

```
function TTDDropdown() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dropdown>
        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
          Dropdown Button
        </Dropdown.Toggle>
        <Dropdown.Menu>
          {tasks.map((mytasks, i) => {
            return (
              <Dropdown.Item key={i} eventKey={"content-" + mytasks.id}>
                {mytasks.title}
              </Dropdown.Item>
            );
          })}
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Source I used to fix it: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/components/dropdowns/

Also, a working app in CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-lamarr-89wzwy